# Using d3d9's backbuffer functionalities correctly

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to write a simple DLL which allow me to take a screenshot of the program calling it.

The program give me its Window Handle using the DLL call.

The CreateDevice functions, CreateOffScreenPlainSurface, works fine using the provided handle, according to HRESULT values returned.

But the output image is blank, then I think that I'm not using the DirectX's GetBackBuffer functions correctly.

Here is how I proceed:

```
HRESULT GFBD_r = g_pd3dDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pSurface);
HRESULT LR_r = pSurface->LockRect(&lr, &rect, D3DLOCK_READONLY);
memcpy(&Frame[0], lr.pBits, Width*Height*4);
pSurface->UnlockRect();
```

My Frame vector is still remaining empty. Maybe the problem came from Multisampling ? I don't exactly understand how does it works, except that i'm using d3dpp.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE; in my    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS    .

Comment: You need to hook a pointer to app's existing [`IDirect3DDevice9`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), used for rendering, not the one created by you. Obviously, it will work only if app is using D3D9 for rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a D3D device for an existing window does not allow you to capture its contents, even if that window is rendered to using hardware acceleration. If there is already a D3D device for the window, the API call to create the device should fail (iirc). If the window is drawn to using regular Windows APIs (i.e. GDI), the D3D content will, depending on the Windows version, be either composed with that other content or behave in an undefined way. Such composition would happen *after* you access the back buffer, and (likely) elsewhere.